# Alternative to uri segment on codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, uri

Im getting the id from a form using

```
  $id=$this->uri->segment(2)
```

I need your help to replace that by something else generic without getting the id from the url 
im using pagination in several pages too & im using

```
$this->uri->segment()
```

too ..

PS:when i want to display a list o programs that belong to a category & when i want to display the list of programs of channel that belong to a category ,the segment change so i wont use the segment i wanna get the id dynamically ..

Best regards

Comment: Then Try with GET method like $_GET['id']

Comment: Why do you want to replace it? What does/doesn't it do that you don't/do need?

Comment: Give this 'Search Results without Query Strings' tutorial a watch: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-search-results-without-query-strings-2/

It uses a database table to store a series of variables and just uses a single id in the url to reference the set of variables and then loads them into the $_GET array. I've used it in a few sites and have found it very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is what you are after, but you can send parameters in a standard codeigniter install with URI and catch them in the method params.

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

    public function index($a = NULL, $b = NULL, $c= NULL)
    {
        echo 'Testing params: <br> 
            Param1: ' . $a . '<br>Param2: ' . $b . '<br>Param3: ' . $c;
    }
}
```

Calling `http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index/test1/test2/test3` will render

```
Testing params: 
Param1: test1
Param2: test2
Param3: test3
```

---

### Example

Going by this comment code:

> foreach $rows as $row .. ..  id; ?>"
>   href="program/details_program/id; ?>">  program_title; ?> page detail.php $id
>   = $this->uri->segment(2); $query = $this->db->get_where('programs', array('id' => $id));

it looks like you have a `program` controller with a `details_program` method that you are linking to and this is where you want a different solution to `uri->segment`. If this is the case, something like this would work with a URL like `http://example.com/program/program_details/123`:

```
class Program extends CI_Controller{

    function program_details($id = NULL){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('programs', array('id' => $id));
    }

}
```

If this isn't what you want, please update the question with all of the relevant (properly formatted) code

Comment: let me explain my point , i have a page that contains all the programs  with a link to detail of a specific program just like this : 

    foreach $rows as $row 
                 ..
                 ..
<a id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>program/details_program/<?php echo $row->id; ?>"> <?php echo $row->program_title; ?>

page detail.php 

             $id = $this->uri->segment(2);
      $query = $this->db->get_where('programs', array('id' => $id));

how to get the id without using uri segment ??

Comment: thank u i'll make change in my code because i've placed

      $this->db->get_where('programs', array('id' => $id));


in the page detail.php